# TFS Rest api - Expand all the related data by a single query

Tags: node.js, tfs, ntlm

I am trying to fetch all the bugs reports from the TFS rest api (not only mine all the others too). I am getting the data by the GET operation, but it's showing only assigned to me. So, now I am using a post opetation with a query. For the authentication purpose I am using an ntlm plugin. Following is my code

```
 var ntlm = require('ntlm')
   , ntlmrequest = require('request').defaults({
     agentClass: require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent
   });
    var url = "https://{instance}/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql?$expand=clauses&api-version=1.0"
      , domain = 'myDomain'
      , username = 'userName'
      , password = 'pwd'
      , hostname ='host';

    var query = "Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [System.State] <> 'Closed' AND [System.State] <> 'Removed' Order By [State] Asc";


    ntlmrequest(url, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': ntlm.challengeHeader(hostname, domain)
            }
        }, function(err, ntlmres) {
                var options = {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: {query:query},
                    json: true,
                    url: url,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': ntlm.responseHeader(ntlmres, url, domain, username, password),
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
                ntlmrequest(options, function (err, ntlmres, body) {
                    if(err)
                    res.json({result:'failed',message:err.message});

                    res.json({result: "success", data: ntlmres.body.workItems});
            });
    });
```

The above code return the following result

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8254,
            "url": "https://{instance}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/8254"
        },
        {
            "id": 8375,
            "url": "https://{instance}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/8375"
        } ]
}
```

My requirement is to get/expand the data of the url which is available on the result instead of the url. Is it possible to get all these data from a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I just changed the url to

```
var url="https://{instance}/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_api/_wit/query?__v=1"
```

and edit the body parameter as shown below

```
body: {wiql:query}
```

It's loading the related data too. The data format as shown below

```
"body"{
    "payload" : {
        "columns" : [
                        System.Id,
                        System.State,
                        System.WorkItemType
                    ],
        "rows" :    [
                        [
                            8050,
                            Resolved,
                            Bug
                        ],
                        [
                            8051,
                            Resolved,
                            Bug
                        ]
                    ]
                }
}
```

Comment: Since it has been resolved, if possible, mark your solution as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)